# How can I convert a URL which is in String datatype to a Route object?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a `URL` stored in a `string`.

const `URL = "http://localhost:8080/employee?name=john"`

I want to convert this `URL` to `route` object so that I can get the `name(query param)` from the `route` object.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `URL` object from that string, then use `searchParams.get` to get the param value :

```js
const urlString = "http://localhost:8080/employee?name=john"

const url = new URL(urlString)

const name = url.searchParams.get('name'); //gives 'john'
```